# How do I explicitly fail a unit test using should.js

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, should.js

I'm using [Mocha](http://mochajs.org) and [Should.js](http://shouldjs.github.io/) to test a promise that I am expecting to generate an error.

Because it is a promise, I don't believe I can simply use `should.throwError()`.  This just means that I would like to fail the unit test in the `.catch` block of the promise.

How do I explicitly fail a unit test using without using some sort of stupid hack like `1.should.equal(2)`?

**Example Code (Which does not work)**

```
it('should throw an error.', function(done) {
  myPromiseGenerator().then(function() {
    should.fail();
    done();
  }).catch(function(e) {
    done();
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the error to the done function.

```
it('should throw an error.', function(done) {
  myPromiseGenerator().then(function() {
    done(new Error("should not succeed"));
  }).catch(function(e) {
    done();
  })
}
```